# Getting A Program's Icon From Handle

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, windows, node-ffi

I'd like to be able to get a programs Icon from its handle (Acquired from User32.dll with EnumWindow/FindWindow), I know of `ExtractAssociatedIcon` but I believe this works from a File instead of a Handle. This questions is perhaps how to convert a Handle to a file location to be converted to a Icon.

My Intent is to port this code to JavaScript via `node-ffi` for use in [node-hide](https://github.com/MrTimcakes/node-hide), my npm module for hiding and showing Windows programs. Making use of a DLL would be easiest, but a C/C# solution will work. I'm just asking for guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use a `shell32.dll` function.

The code:

```
// Required namespaces.
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Import the function.
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint="ExtractAssociatedIcon")]
public static extern IntPtr ExtractAssociatedIcon(IntPtr hInst, string lpIconPath, out ushort lpiIcon);

// Now get the icon.
ushort uicon;
IntPtr handle = ExtractAssociatedIcon(this.Handle, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, out uicon);
Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(handle);
```